# Flutter local notifications custom sound not working in background and in kill state

Tags: flutter, audio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added two custom channels for each sound and created different functions for each channel. custom sound it working fine on foreground but in kill state or in background the custom sound don't work.

I have created different channels and different functions for each sound.

This is for default notifications :

```
 static showDefualtLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    // AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'YOUR_DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID',
      'high_importance_channel',
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: isNotificationsSoundOff,
    );

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetail =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id, channel.name,
      importance: Importance.max,
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      // other properties...
    );
    if (notification != null) {
      var notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetail,
      );

      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(notification.hashCode,
          notification.title, notification.body, notificationDetails,
          payload: message.data.toString());
    }
  }
```

And below two are with custom sounds :

```
  static showAdoreLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    // AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetail =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      adoreChannel.id, adoreChannel.name,
      importance: Importance.max,
      channelDescription: 'Adore channel description',
      icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      sound: adoreChannel.sound,
      // additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[4]),
      // other properties...
    );
    if (notification != null) {
      var notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetail,
      );
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(notification.hashCode,
          notification.title, notification.body, notificationDetails,
          payload: message.data.toString());
    }
  }
```

```
  static showPsstLocalNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    // AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetail =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      psstChannel.id, psstChannel.name,
      importance: Importance.max,
      channelDescription: 'Psst channel description',
      icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
      priority: Priority.high,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      sound: psstChannel.sound,
      // additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[4]),
      // other properties...
    );
    if (notification != null) {
      var notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetail,
      );
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(notification.hashCode,
          notification.title, notification.body, notificationDetails,
          payload: message.data.toString());
    }
  }
```